# auto-incrementing ID on my JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, auto-increment

I've been trying to do this for a while now and I just can't seem to get it right. [One post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898674/auto-increment-id-json?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) got me very close but not quite there because my of JSON's hierarchy. (it's an assignment and this hierarchy is mandatory.)

What I do right now is submit info from one page, POST it to my php on another page, save it in an array there, json_encode that array and write that to my JSON file.

Here is my watered-down code, hopefully getting rid of most unnecessary code:

```
<?php

$filename = "json/exercises.json";
$filesize = filesize($filename);
$fp = fopen($filename, "r+");

#Accept the submitted form
$exLanguage = $_POST['exLanguage'];
$exTitle = $_POST['exTitle'];
$exStuff = $_POST['exStuff'];

#write to JSON with an incrementing ID
if (file_get_contents($filename) == "") {
  $exercise = array (
    "id" => 1,
    "lang" => $exLanguage,
    "title" => $exTitle,
    "main_object" =>
      [
      "exStuff" => $exStuff
      ]
  );
  $exercise_json = json_encode($exercise, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  file_put_contents($filename, $exercise_json, FILE_APPEND);

} else {

  #Get the last set ID
  $jsonid = json_decode(fread($fp, $filesize), true);
  $last = end($jsonid);
  $title = prev($jsonid);
  $lang = prev($jsonid);
  $id = prev($jsonid);

  $exercise = array (
    "id" => ++$id,
    "lang" => $exLanguage,
    "title" => $exTitle,
    "main_object" =>
      [
      "exStuff" => $exStuff
      ]
  );
  $exercise_json = json_encode($exercise, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  file_put_contents($filename, $exercise_json, FILE_APPEND);
}

?>
```

now what this does is if my json is empty it adds the first array correctly with the ID at 1. Then if I try to add to my json again it adds it correctly with the ID at 2. But any more attempted writes to the JSON will give me these errors:

> Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
>
> Warning: prev() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
>
> Warning: prev() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
>
> Warning: prev() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

I tried doing a

```
$reset = reset($jsonid);
```

after writing to file but that didn't work, just gave me another error on the 3rd write for the reset being given a null too.

Can anyone please tell me how to get this too work? Or if there is a much easier way of getting this done?

Comment: This is a 50:50 guess here. You `$fp = fopen($filename, "r+");` which makes `$fp` and array line by line of the file. Then you `$jsonid = json_decode(fread($fp, $filesize), true);` and `$fp` is still an array. I assume this will not work. I think `$jsonid = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true);` may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand JSON format first. Its a collection of Objects which means `attribute: value` pair wrapped in `{}` and separated by comma `,` and then again wrapped in `{}` OR `[]` at top level.

Your JSON structure is incomplete or corrupted. What you are doing currently will create JSON in following format in your JSON file:

```
{ "id": 1, "lang": "as", "title": "asdsad" }
{ "id": 2, "lang": "as", "title": "asdsad" }
{ "id": 3, "lang": "as", "title": "asdsad" }
{ "id": 4, "lang": "as", "title": "asdsad" }
```

So `json_decode` will return `null` in this case because of invalid JSON format.

You need to keep appending your new JSON in existing JSON such that above format will become like this:

```
[
    { "id": 1, "lang": "as", "title": "asdsad" },
    { "id": 2, "lang": "as", "title": "asdsad" },
    { "id": 3, "lang": "as", "title": "asdsad" },
    { "id": 4, "lang": "as", "title": "asdsad" }
]
```

Which means your `else` block is incorrect. Use following code in `else` block:

```
$jsonid = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true);
$last = end($jsonid);
$id = $last['id'];

$jsonid[] = array (
    "id" => ++$id,
    "lang" => $exLanguage,
    "title" => $exTitle,
    "main_object" => array("exStuff" => $exStuff)
);
$exercise_json = json_encode($jsonid, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents($filename, $exercise_json, FILE_APPEND);
```

I hope you are not bound to use that incorrect/corrupted JSON format. That will not work with `json_decode()` in any case.

Comment: Well this gives me the same result, just without all the prevs. I get the second write with the id 2 and on the 3rd write the id 1 and the warning Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I used the wrong variable while encoding json. It should be `$jsonid` not `$exercise`. Code updated. Check now.